# Pull a result set from MySQL and then filter/search through it on the client side?

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, database

I have an online order form where the user should be able to type in a SKU and quantity and then (hopefully) when they are typing in the next one, jQuery has dynamically filled in the remaining fields (name, price, etc) for the previously entered item.

The product info is all within a MySQL database and I am perfectly okay with running the query to return all products ahead of time as it isn't a huge database of products. I'm running PHP as the server-side language.

One thing I do  not want to do is refresh the page. The user should be able to enter the customer info, all products and options and have a final total price calculated on the fly before they need to click 'submit' and see any page loads.

I'm not even 100% sure this can be done, but I've seen more complex stuff online!

If anybody can help out at all, I'd greatly appreciate it!

Comment: This can be done. What is your question?

Comment: The question is basically how to do it. I have low-to-medium skills with all of the technologies I mentioned, so I'm iffy on how to tackle this. I was thinking perhaps I might be able to convert the MySQL result set to a PHP array, but that would still require page refreshes. Is there a way to loop through the result set with jQuery and create a jQuery array perhaps?

Comment: Why does converting a result set to a PHP array require a page refresh? Have you heard of [tag:ajax]?

Comment: I don't have any experience with AJAX unfortunately. I was referring to the fact that once the result set was converted to the PHP array it would still require a page refresh to search the PHP array for the data I need each time the user entered a new item.

Answer (score 1):

I've had excellent experiences with [jQuery DataTables](http://datatables.net/), take a look at the website, there's a lot of examples and also PHP code to get you on your way on how you want everything to work. Takes around 15 - 30 minutes to do what you want with this plugin.

Here's an [example](http://datatables.net/release-datatables/examples/data_sources/server_side.html) on the website that uses PHP processing.